# fix url using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm using jquery mobile to building a site but when I click on a button and this button points to a dialog page, in the URL appears `#&ui-state=dialog`. If I put in the `<a data-ajax="false"></a>` the url is correct without `#&ui-state=dialog` but the dialog window doesn't show correctly because obviously ajax is disable.there is some way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the dialog, use `$.mobile.changePage()` and set the `changeHash` option to `false`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html

```
//delegate the event binding so elements in the DOM now and in the future will be bound-to
$(document).delegate('#my-dialog-button', 'click', function () {

    //change to the dialog, forcing the hash to remain the same and the page to be viewed as a dialog
    $.mobile.changePage($('#my-dialog'), {
        changeHash : false,
        role       : 'dialog'
    });
});
```

Comment: well the function works but in this way the page is showed only as a page and not anymore as a dialog like if ajax was disabled

Comment: Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qzzW5/. The page opens as a dialog in every browser I tested.

Comment: I tried my example in the jsfiddle and works correctly.but in my page doesn't work.maybe could be because I used in a page previously to post a form data-ajax="false"?

Comment: I couldn't say, if you can post a link to your site I could check-it-out.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.I tried out the fiddle posted by Jasper.Its working fine.When I update the jquery mobile version it stopped working.And also the dialogue box is not able to be closed.
Is there any other way of doing this?That would be a great help.

Answer (score 17):

Try to use data-history="false" in the popup div tag like:

```
<div data-history="false" data-role="popup" id="options-list-div" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="b">
```

Good luck! :-)

Comment: For me it doesnt work.. If I add data-history="false" it doesnt add the #&ui-state=dialog but it still goes back to the first page and it doesnt move to the next one exactly like before (after a while it should move to a new page). And if I add the "changeHash" inside the changePage function nothing happens..

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why, but Jasper example doesn't work when I try integrating it too.

I was using `data-*` attributes on the button for configuring the dialog box.

Now I declare all the options in the `changePage` function, and it works fine.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="#my-dialog-button"></a>
```

---

```
$("#my-dialog-button").click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "page_containing_the_dialog.html", {
        type: "get",
        transition: 'pop',
        role: 'dialog',
        changeHash : false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `changeHash` would disable the change of history because the url won't change. 
So if the user clicks/taps the close button , it would propagate to the previous page if there was any.

Also it might cause a problem when the user taps the **back** button on the mobile since there was no history change when the popup was opened, it would again take the user back to the previous page rather than closing the popup, which would be incorrect behaviour.

Instead of `changeHash` if we use `transition` it would work like a dialog and let the hash change the history too.

@Vincentp have you tried removing the `changeHash` property from the 'changePage' call, now that you are using `transition` ?

```
$("#my-dialog-button").click(function () {
    var default_transition = "pop";
    $.mobile.changePage("page_containing_the_dialog.html", {
        role : 'dialog',
        transition: $(this).data('transition') || default_transition
    });
    return false;
});
```