# #&ui-state=dialog appear automatically when call popup and make error when refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile

I strat 192.168.1.102:8080 to call my server but the url change it into...

```
http://192.168.1.102:8080/#&ui-state=dialog
```

Instead of

```
http://192.168.1.102:8080
```

which make an error if I refresh the browser. I don't know why it happen like that???

here is my code I call popup to start first to get username

```
window.onload = function(){

    $('#popupLogin').popup("open","slidedown");

}
```

Here is My popup that I call

```
<!--POPUP IN THE START UP || NOTE** data-dismissible='false' = Prevent popup close when click outside -->
<div data-role="popup" data-dismissible='false' id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a"
     class="ui-corner-all ui-popup ui-body-a ui-overlay-shadow" aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false"
     data-shadow="true" data-corners="true" data-transition="slidedown" data-position-to="origin">

    <form id="startDialog" onsubmit="startActivity()">
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Express Your Feeling</h3>
            <!--ID = username, geoFeeling-->
            <input required type="text" id="username" value="" placeholder="username"
                data-theme="a" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <textarea required id="geoFeeling" value="" placeholder="Feeling..." style="height: 70px"
                data-theme="a" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" data-theme="b" >Log in</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<!--------------------------------------------------END OF POPUP --------------------------------------->
```

and after user completed the form and submit form will call another function to start activity.

Popup box will disappear.

I don't know which part that i was wrong because at the beginning

I can refresh browser and popup will re-open again (re-start activity)

but now URL has change (because of what??) after develop I can't refresh it anymore

Do you have any suggestion or somethings ???

Please Advise.

Comment: There's an easy solution to your problem. Don't start your app with popup. Use normal jQM page for a user authorization. This text "/#&ui-state=dialog" is created when popup and dialog box are created.

Comment: I just call my popup to be open this doesn't mean I start with popup sir?? I didn't create any popup just call it open??

Comment: Again, if you are going to implement authorization, do not use popup for that. /#&ui-state=dialog is integral part of popup and dialog box handling.

Comment: I didn't use for authorization also Just to get some info from user.for first time I use it It didn't show this state at all  /#&ui-state=dialog

Comment: now I try to use     $('#popupLogin').popup("close");

to close it but it close stop all activity???

Comment: Try this:[UI popup URL solution]


: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957361/1212141

Comment: I think this question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317297/fix-url-using-jquery-mobile/22957361#22957361